# Add AdWords Search terms as "Phrase match" or "Exact Match" and Add to negative as "Phrase match"

Tags: google-ads-api

Using AdWords WEB admin is sometime difficult to protect money loss on one hand but it's liberate on how you spend your money.

When i use "Search Terms" console I like to add new search terms that drive conversions into keywords ( if they aren't exist - i check via filter ).

Another favorite act of mine is to add to the negative keywords list search terms that doesn't perform well.

The problem is that AdWords console suggest to **ADD** keywords as "**Broad Match**" and when i add to negative keywords the suggestion is to add as [**Exact Match**].

It's fairly easy to change "**Broad Match**" into "**Phrase Match**" or [**Exact Match**] for small amount of keywords by adding quotation marks or brackets but who about long list?

Same for adding as negative, It's hard to change 50 keywords from Exact Match to Phrase. You'll need to remove 100 brackets and add 100 quotation marks manually.

So how to speed the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with few simple JavaScript scripts to speed the process.

I Created a favorite Tab on chrome browser containing these favorites:

1. Replace [ with "
2. add "
3. add []

and for the sake of the new dashboard i created :

1. new add "
2. new add []

Each script does simple job and the titles are self explanatory, use these scripts to speed up your work:

**Replace [ with "**

```
javascript:var targetDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");var m=0;for (var i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; ++i) { if (targetDiv[i].type=='text' && targetDiv[i].value.indexOf("]")>0) {targetDiv[i].value=targetDiv[i].value.replace('[','"');targetDiv[i].value=targetDiv[i].value.replace(']','"');}}
```

**Add "**

```
javascript:var targetDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"); var m=0; for (var i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; ++i) { if (targetDiv[i].type=='text' && targetDiv[i].className=='gwt-TextBox') {targetDiv[i].value='"' + targetDiv[i].value + '"'}}
```

**Add []**

```
javascript:var targetDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"); var m=0; for (var i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; ++i) { if (targetDiv[i].type=='text' && targetDiv[i].className=='gwt-TextBox' && targetDiv[i].value!='') {targetDiv[i].value='[' + targetDiv[i].value + ']'}}
```

**new add "**

```
javascript:var targetDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"); var m=0; for (var i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; ++i) { if (targetDiv[i].type=='text' && targetDiv[i].className=='input _ngcontent-fnf-85') {targetDiv[i].value='"' + targetDiv[i].value + '"'}}
```

**new add []**

```
javascript:var targetDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"); var m=0; for (var i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; ++i) { if (targetDiv[i].type=='text' && targetDiv[i].className=='input _ngcontent-uml-42' && targetDiv[i].value!='') {targetDiv[i].value='[' + targetDiv[i].value + ']'}}
```

Use those scripts whenever you want to change mass keywords on the search terms console, Just click "Add as keywords" or "Add as negative keywords" and choose your favorite action.

Here's an example of what **Add "** will do:
[image: favorite link 2 will do this]